# Let $(M, \tau)$ a topological space, $N$ a smooth manifold and $f: M \to N$ a continuous map. If exists an maximal atlas on $M$ such that

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Let $(M, \tau)$ a topological space, $N$ a smooth manifold and $f: M \to N$ a continuous map. If exists a maximal  atlas $\mathcal{A}$ on $M$ such that $\tau=\tau_{\mathcal{A}}$ and $f$ is a smooth immersion, how I can prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is unique?

Comment: What do you mean by "$f$ is unique"?

Comment: Sorry, $\mathcal{A}$ is unique

Comment: What is an atlas on a topological space?

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem? Did you try to consider the case of an embedding for instance?